# My gun starts shooting rapidly when I dont look at a game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Essentially I have shooting system that works with a firerate Equation so that once timeSinceLastShot is greater than 1f / (fireRate / 60f), the method CanShoot() returns a true bool. This allows the shoot method to run which inturn calls the AfterShoot() method which invokes an event so things like the muzzle flash and gun sound run. The problem I have is that for some reason when im not aimed at an object (like in the sky), AfterShoot() or another method relating to it is called super fast which creates a very loud unwanted noise with the gun sounds and a very flashy muzzle flash.

Also im new to c# and unity so my code is kinda unorganized and inefficient so sorry about that.

```
private void Awake(){

        maxDistance = gunData.maxDistance;
        fireRate = gunData.fireRate;
        damage = gunData.damage;

        InputManager.startShootInput += IsShooting;
        InputManager.stopShootInput += NotShooting;
        InputManager.afterShoot += MuzzleFlash;
        InputManager.afterShoot += GunSoundEffect;
    }


  private bool CanShoot(){
        return (isShooting && (timeSinceLastShot > 1f / (fireRate / 60f)));
    }


  private void Update(){


        timeSinceLastShot += Time.deltaTime;

        if(CanShoot()){
            Shoot();
        }
    }

  private void Shoot() {

        RaycastHit hitInfo;

///CODE TALKING ABOUT RAYCASTS KINDA USELESSS IN THIS PROBLEM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxDistance)){
            if (hitInfo.transform != null){
                timeSinceLastShot = 0;

                IDamageable damageable = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<IDamageable>();
                damageable?.TakeDamage(damage);

                GameObject instantiatedImpact = Instantiate(impactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
                instantiatedImpact.transform.SetParent(hitInfo.transform);
            }
        }  





        AfterShoot();  
    }


    private void AfterShoot() {
        Debug.Log("I am being called");
        InputManager.afterShoot?.Invoke();
    }
```

Comment: At least `AfterShoot();` is always called within `Shoot` regardless of you aiming at something - which kinda seems to make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always set timeSinceLastShot=0 when shooting. You only cleared it when you point at something.

```
  private void Shoot() {

    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    timeSinceLastShot = 0;

    if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hitInfo, maxDistance)){
        if (hitInfo.transform != null){
            IDamageable damageable = hitInfo.transform.GetComponent<IDamageable>();
            damageable?.TakeDamage(damage);

            GameObject instantiatedImpact = Instantiate(impactEffect, hitInfo.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hitInfo.normal));
            instantiatedImpact.transform.SetParent(hitInfo.transform);
        }
    }  

    AfterShoot();  
}
```